# An error occurred while listing cloudwatch-logs relations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a log group connector lambda that creates a trigger automatically to a splunk forwarder lambda for every new log group.

What is the meaning of the following error on my splunk forwarder lambda?

```
An error occurred while listing cloudwatch-logs relations: 2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'logGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+; Value '' at 'logGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1 (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 4d7fdfbc-4ad0-47ec-875f-b172e45c714b)
```

Can anyone shed any light please how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this problem and finally found the solution. The error message is misleading by the way.

My problem was that in my **Function Policy** I had something like:

`"AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:sa-east-1:1234567890:log-group:*"`

Note the `*` at the end -- that was the problem.

I ended up adding one permission per trigger.

EDIT:
The above is the solution IF you're setting 'logGroupName' correctly, but your Function Policy matches the one I described.

Comment: Can I please see your CloudFormation template?